# Groovy configslurper not accepting strings in input

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, config

I want to preface by saying this all worked until SCM redid the jenkins instance, I'm unsure of what they changed but it broke this.

I have a config:

```
program {
AS{
   server=["serv1","serv2","serv3"]
}
}
```

in my script I use this to get the config

```
def String groovy_properties_file = "/path/to/scripts/config.groovy"
def config = new ConfigSlurper().parse(new File(groovy_properties_file).toURL())
```

I was originaly taking in parameters for which program to use but now it seems to be giving me an error when a string is used rather than the config is hardcoded.

so for example:

```
def programConfig = config.program.AS
```

and

```
def programConfig = config.program."AS"
```

Work Just fine.

but setting AS to a variable such as

```
    String progString =  "AS"
    def programConfig = config.program."${progString}"

  if(!programConfig ){
  //Error Case
}
```

That hits the error case and throws an exception. I cant quite figure out the difference or what changed to cause this.

Comment: use  `config.program[progString]`

Comment: or `config.program.get(progString)`

Comment: This is where I ended up. It was a little odd that it suddenly decided to to not accept the old syntax. I'm assuming the groovy version got changed underneath me.